# What are the Best Ways to Serialize a Pandas PivotTable

Tags: python, python-2.7, serialization

How can I serialize and deserialize a pivot table in pandas (see example below)? I tried a few different ways already like csv, json, pickles, etc, but none of them worked when I try to deserialize the data back to objects.

```
>>> table = pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'],
...                     columns=['C'], aggfunc=np.sum)
>>> table
          small  large
foo  one  1      4
     two  6      NaN
bar  one  5      4
     two  6      7
```

Update: I tried pickle but it was not satisfying because I need to send the data to an in-house database and I want to avoid writing on the disk - maybe I was wrong but I could not pass a buffer as an argument to the pd.to_pickle method.

Comment: pickle should be able to store and load any Python object

Comment: Thanks. I tried but I want to avoid writing on disk. Any advise how I can do that?